# How to disable Raspberry Pi console output to monitor but keep rendering graphics

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, tty

I'm building an application on Raspberry Pi that renders some GUI to the screen. I would like to keep rendering the GUI but get rid of all the "ugly" console logs during boot or when the GUI crashes, so the user doesn't see them.

I'm not a hardcore Linux expert. My question is - is it some general mechanism in the Linux kernel that controls what and how is written to the console? Or is there some special Raspberrpy Pi specific logic? Is there a way to turn it off?

Some more technical details:

- Raspberry Pi 3B/B+
- Alpine Linux 3.10

Comment: May be this would be possible using the Raspi4 using the seconds hdmi output only?

Comment: @Robert unfortunatelly not my case, I gotta use rpi 3

Comment: Then I would use the custom boot screen as described [here](https://raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-operating-systems/raspbian/custom-boot-up-screen) and add some sort of watchdog that reboots the device in case the UI crashes.

Comment: I already have a solution similar to this one, however this is more of a hack, not a real solution. I'd like to actually turn off the console, not just hide it